# Datetime picker in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

How do I change the datetimepicker to only show time in visual basic? I use the databinding source between access and vb. In my database, the time is showing eg 7:30am, but in datetimepicker in visual basic, date is shown for that field.

```
Private Sub TimeDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TimeDateTimePicker.ValueChanged
  TimeDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time 
  TimeDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = True
  DateTimePicker.value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mmtt")     
End Sub
```

Comment: i have no idea of how to start. May i ask what is the first step?or just have to type code in the datetimepicker to change it?thanks

Comment: Have a look at the properties of datetimepicker. Are you doing a web form?

Comment: the properties show this:20/3/2014 7:12 PM <<but i only want the value to be 7:12PM...no im nt doing web form. Can you guide me on this,how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
   DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time

 DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = True
```

Or alternatively...

```
 DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
 DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mmtt"
 DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = True
```

Set time...Or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805775/datetimepicker-control-how-to-set-time) post...

```
 DateTimePicker.value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mmtt") 'THIS WORKS SEE IMAGE BELOW
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot, it works alrdy. May i ask how to set the time following the computer time and disable user from editing?

Comment: How to set the time following the computer time?

Comment: Value of '1/1/0001 8:27:00 PM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value ...why error shows this?

Comment: What happens if you take the to string off

Comment: cannot without tostring  Error 1 'Public Shared ReadOnly Property Now As Date' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed. datetime.now has curly line below it

Comment: TimeDateTimePicker.Value = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)  this code still unable to show my system time.

Comment: The solution provided: DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mmtt") DOES WORK. I just tested this, I thought it did. What is your issue then?

Comment: Also, if all your doing is displaying a time this is overkill; use a label or something else especially if your not going to be interacting with the control anyways because you want to disable it.

Comment: Value of '1/1/0001 1:26:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'<<<this is the error after i put that line of code(......"HHmmtt").  For the first two lines of code given by you is already ok, will show only time.but is not the system time.

Comment: What do you mean it's not the system time, it sure is and I can guarantee you that. If you don't believe me here's from Microsoft: "Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time."

Comment: And here is the link to that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also that is the same exact code I am using and it works just fine on my end. If you put a new DateTimePicker on a form and paste the code I have given you and run it, it will work.

Comment: u look at my error again. I go and see the properties of the datetimepicker and its value in the properties section is a long date(20/3/2014 7:12 PM).

Comment: Can you post your code up top along with a screenshot and I can help you further. Something is going on that is changing this...

Comment: i stated earlier that i linked with my database access, is there any problem with that?

Comment: Link to what? You wanted the current time of computer to this DateTimePicker and it works. Whatever else your doing with it I don't know...